# Express.js POST response 'Object moved to here' iDoklad API

Tags: express, request

I have an Angular and Express application that first logs user to external site using

```
<a href='url'></a>
```

after login it redirects back to my page with authorization code, so that in browser I have https://faktury-12.herokuapp.com/?code=fbbe4311532df4e098f1f7086774669a
 - then I send that code to back end

```
app.get('/oi', (req,res,next) => {
    const code = req.query.code;
    request.post('https://app.idoklad.cz/identity/server/connect/token&grant_type=authorization_code&client_id=cbf4f262-025e-4b2f-bf6a-0cbee25dda4a'+
      '&client_secret=8a218922-b512-48x3-892e-aa2a847e141a&scope=idoklad_api%20offline_access&code=' + code +
      '&redirect_uri=https://faktury-12.herokuapp.com/', (request,response)=>{
          const object = response.body;
          res.send(object);
      })
})
```

and use that authorization code to get a token from there as well, but the response in network tab in 'Object moved to here'. I looked it up and found it has something to do with redirection - that it is set to null. I reset it but still the same.

when I add

```
res.redirect('https://faktury-12.herokuapp.com/')
```

before or after

```
res.send(object)
```

it takes me back to my homepage and does not deliver anything

I expect res.body to look like this

```
{
  "access_token": "eyJ0eXAi...",
  "expires_in": 6000,
  "token_type": "Bearer",
  "refresh_token": "abcd..."
}
```

but it says 'Object moved to here' in the network tab

this is href to mentioned object

```
<a href="%2fidentity%2fHome%2fE404%3faspxerrorpath%3d%2fidentity%2fserver%2fconnect%2ftokengrant_type%3dauthorization_code%26client_id%3dcbf3f192-025e-4b2f-bf6a-0cbee25dda4a%26client_secret%3d8a210622-b512-48e3-892e-aa2a847e141a%26scope%3didoklad_api%2520offline_access%26code%3d7036741cf29bf898be3186c70a573b86%26redirect_uri%3dhttp%3a%2flocalhost%3a5000%2foi">here</a>
```

I would like to understand, what is happening
I appreciate any help, I have been stuck with this for some time, so thanks for your time